# Python 3 Can Someone Explain How This Is Indexed?

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

new user here so please be understanding if my question/code isn't quite up to par and I'll take any suggestions into account.

The code is designed to count the amount of substrings (sb) in the string (s) and print the results.

I'd basically like for someone to explain how this code is indexed. The thing I'm not quite understanding is the "for i in range" portion, specifically the indexing where the variable i (range of the length of the string 's') is used to start and then the sum of i and the sub_len being the ending (that's what's confusing me). Then if that's equal to the substring(sb) it 1 adds to the result. I almost understand it after a couple of hours of reading and playing around with it. Please feel free to explain the entirety of the code so that it may help any other newbies out there. Thanks for any help.

```
    s = 'my given stringstringstring'
    sb = 'string'
    count = 0

    sub_len = len(sb)

    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i:i+sub_len] == sb:
            count += 1

    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity of this answer, I'll be acting on the assumption `s = "stringstringstring"`. The principles given below will be correct for any given starting string and sub string.

I believe that the first four lines are relatively self-explanatory, so I'll start with the for loop.

The first line, `for i in range (len(s)):`, causes this loop to execute once for each letter in the string `s`.

The core of it is the index command, `s[i:i+sub_len]`. What this does is it starts with `i = 0` for the first execution. If sb is 'string', then `len(sb) = 6`. This means that `s[i:i+sub_len]` simplifies to `s[0:6]`, which starts at the first character (index 0) and includes the second, third, fourth, fifth, and sixth characters. This is equal to "string". Because `sb` is also equal to "string" the if statement will be evaluated to `True`, and count will increase by 1.

For the second iteration, `i = 1`. This means that `s[i:i+sublen]` simplifies to `s[1:7]`, which starts at the *second* character includes the third, fourth, fifth, sixth, and *seventh* characters. This is equal to "trings", which isn't equal to `sb`. The if will evaluate as `False`, and count won't be increased.

The next iteration will simplify to `s[2:7]`, which is "ringst". Each iteration will evaluate as `False` until iteration 7, where the indexing simplifies to `s[6:12]`. This is once again equal to "string", and the if will once again evaluate to `True`.